# Cannot send/receive mail from Gmail Business on webmail

Tags: email-server, gmail, email-bounces, webmail

Good day everyone, Recently we setup a WordPress site for a client. The clients' domain name was bought from GoDaddy and is hosted on a GoDaddy VPS. The issue I'm facing is that the webmail account associated with the site can send/receive emails to and from Gmail/Yahoo and other email providers but when I try to send an email from my work email (which uses google apps for business) it bounces back. Similarly, I cannot send an email from the webmail to my work email as well. I do not know what the problem could be. Thanks in advance.

### Domain DNS Records

Type Name Value TTL Actions

A @ 50.XXX.XXX.XXX 1 Hour
A mail 50.XXX.XXX.XXX 1 Hour
CNAME www @ 1 Hour
MX @ mail.clientwebsite.com (Priority: 0) 1 Hour
NS @ ns23.domaincontrol.com 1 Hour
NS @ ns24.domaincontrol.com 1 Hour

[This is what I get when the email bounces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyP02.jpg)

Comment: do you have some error to report from your email bounced back?

Comment: @FedericoGalli see the image attached. That is the message I receive when I try to send an email from my work email to the client's webmail.